# HTMLFormElement.reportValidity() ignore "display:none" input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm sending a form using an ajax call. When the user uses the submit button within the form, this calls a function `sendForm()`. The function prevents the default (submitting the form), and validates the form (for fields with `required`) and if the form is valid then makes the ajax call.

Problem is that the form contains some hidden (`display:none`) elements, which are validated using the `resportValidity()` call, and therefore the form fails because of the hidden elements, which should not be validated (they are displayed depending on the previous user options).

Below the `sendForm()` function used:

```js
function sendForm(e) {
  $(e).preventDefault;

  var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

  if (form.reportValidity()) { 

      // form is valid, do ajax call..

  }else{

    alert("Form not valid");

  }
}
```

So when it does `form.reportValidity()` I get false because of "empty" `required` input fields from the inputs with `display:none` style.

How can I just reportValidity() the form elements without `display:none`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want an element to be included in the form when checking for validity, you should `disable` the element.  At the time you set `display: none` you should also add the `disabled` attribute.

[Documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute:barred-from-constraint-validation)

Comment: Interestingly this works for required but executed if pattern is also used.